# We've blacklisted [engine], should we do the same for the other similar tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

This is a follow up of a previous question about [doing something with the tags `API` and `SDK`](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2389/could-we-rename-the-tags-api-and-sdk-to-api-development-and-sdk-developme), which made me realize they were not alone, and that they might be useless.

It is also a follow up of [this question](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2391/how-should-we-use-the-engine-tag) asking about the usage of the `engine` tag, where the conclusion was that the tag was not needed as it was a meta-tag.

Should we do the same for the following engine-like tags, where the descriptions are ok but, don't contain tag usage?

- [api](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api)
- [framework](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/framework)
- [libraries](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/libraries)
- [sdk](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sdk)

Is there a case where one of these could not be tagged with their specific API/Framework/Library/SDK, or with [architecture](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/architecture), or with [software-engineering](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-engineering), or with another more specific tag?

---

If you feel a tag should be added to this list, please add them, or leave a comment.

Comment: I've removed all of the uses of "sdk" and put it on the blacklist.

Comment: Same for 'framework'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am of the opinion that these tags should be blacklisted.

- You would not be able to use the tags by themselves to adequately tag a question, unless the question was only specific to general context. Such context would probably be to broad for our scope.
- To more accurately use the tags, you would have to *also* use the more specific tag to provide context, in which case these tags are only being used as meta tags. On brief review, this appears to be the current most recent usage of these tags.

Comment: I could argue with this by saying, that you can use them by themselves when you want to make your own engine/framework/library, but that doesn't add anything to the questiom and thus they're still pointless.

Comment: @Bálint, that was my reasoning behind use of the engine tag. It was pointed out that such questions are also too broad for our scope, by nature.